# MySQL Select exact word

Tags: mysql, select, exact-match

I currently have database items with "Skönhet Kroppsvård Massage Spa" as category (in one string).

Currently I use

```
     WHERE Select6 LIKE '%spa%'
```

What I want is to select eg. "Spa" and get the fields containing "Spa" and not "Spas"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look into [mySQL fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). It takes some time to get into and has some caveats, but it's probably the only sane way to fulfill your requirement.

[Boolean full-text searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) should work for you, for example

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
AGAINST ('+Spa' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: I guess that this is the way I must go.. but it´s to hard for me :/

Comment: @Mackelito is the example above not working for you? Adding a fulltext index to `Select6` and doing `....MATCH (Select6)....` should work

Comment: I´m currently trying to change how a extension to Joomla fetches items.. and the select query is built in some automagic  way.. cant figure it out :(

Answer (score 1):

Try following condition, one checks for word spa anywhere in text and other at end.

```
WHERE Select6 LIKE '% spa %' or Select6 LIKE '% spa' or Select6 LIKE 'spa' or Select6 LIKE 'spa %'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the '%' at the end. That symbol is equivalent to saying "any string here". So when you do %spa%, it will match any string that contains spa somewhere in the middle.

If all your strings are formatted as you said and your search term is always at the end, just do '%spa'. This way it will find you strings that end with "Spa".

So, for example: WHERE Select6 LIKE '%Spa'

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
WHERE Select6 LIKE '%spa%' AND NOT LIKE '%spas%'
```

this will take xxxxspaxxxx but not xxxxspasxxxx

So it will work if spa is not the last word or the first one

Or

> WHERE Select6 LIKE '% spa %' OR Select6 LIKE '% spa' OR Select6 LIKE 'spa %' OR Select6 LIKE 'spa' OR

spa at the end `'% spa'`

spa at the begining `'spa %'`

only spa `'spa'`

Comment: what about words like spar, spade, span, etc

Comment: What I understand with this question is that he wants anything with spa but not spas

Comment: He mentioned that as an example :)

Comment: Then sorry I dont see the problem, just add space like this '% spa %'

Comment: I tried this but WHERE Select6 LIKE '% spa %' gave no result?

Comment: It's normal, add what rs said. You have to check if it's at the end like this "% spa" or at the begining like "spa % I just didn't want to copy what he said :P cause it would be cheating. I didn't understand your question at first. sorry

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove % at the end of position. Because both side % search "Spa" in word not end of position.

   where Select6 LIKE '%Spa

I like [@rs.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125551/rs) way because if you forgot the trim, you have that rows too, so use this way

```
 where Select6 LIKE '%Spa %' or Select6 LIKE '%Spa'
```